# Estimating integrals.

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=(\tan x)^{3/2}-3\tan x+ \sqrt{\tan x}$.

Consider three integrals and arrange them in decreasing order:

$I_1=\int_0^1 f(x)dx,$ $I_2=\int_{0.3}^{1.3} f(x)dx,$ $I_3=\int_{0.5}^{1.5} f(x)dx$

I tried to integrate but couldn't, but we should probably estimate it differently.

It doesn't help if we take $\tan x=t$ (since $\tan x$ is increasing) and simplify. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first term will dominate as $x$ approaches $\frac\pi2$, so it looks like the integrals are given in increasing order.

Comment: @saulspatz no, the answer is $I_1>I_3>I_2$.

Comment: Yes, numerical integration bears that out.  $I_1\approx-.55,\ I_2\approx-1.1,\ I_3\approx-.88$  My intuition about this is very wrong.  I thought $I_3$ would be large and positive.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* If you use the substitution $y=\sqrt {\tan x},$ the integrand becomes $$\frac{2y^2(y^2-3y+1)\mathrm dy}{y^4+1}.$$