# Approximate the same integral on different range of same length

Tags: calculus, integration, approximate-integration

Let $f(x)=(\tan x)^{\frac{3}{2}}-3\tan x+\sqrt{\tan x}.$ Consider the three integrals
$$
I_1=\int_0^1f(x)\ dx, I_2=\int_{0.3}^{1.3}f(x)\ dx, I_3=\int_{0.5}^{1.5}f(x)\ dx
$$
Then how to show that $I_1>I_3>I_2.$

Can we solve it without solving the integral?

Comment: what have you tried

Comment: Have you plotted $f$ to get some insight into where $f$ is big/small, positive/negative, et c., to help select strategies for what you are trying to show?

Comment: @Quantum I have tried to directly integrate it, but failed.

Comment: @Eric Towers, Yes I have tried but at very few points and finally couldn't conclude anything.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Observe that one of the integrals is totally negative. Also, you may gain intuition about what to actually try to prove by sketching the graph.

---

Below is the graph in the segment that is needed:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's fine but how do you draw the graph on your own. Or prove this analytically.

Comment: @Harvey Can you provide the source of the problem? What are you supposed to use? Is this problem intended to do by numerical analysis or what?

Comment: I have seen two duplicates of this questions but neither have a rigorous answer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191975/compare-values-of-the-three-definite-integrals-given-fx-tan-x-frac32-3-ta?rq=1

Comment: and: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3721981/estimating-integrals?rq=1

Comment: @Harvey : [Curve sketching[(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_sketching) is the easy part -- critical points, inflection points, concavity, and endpoints.  (Critical points: $\tan x \leq 0$ or $1-6\sqrt{\tan x} + 3 \tan x = 0$.  Then use the second derivative for concavities...)